# Machine-Readable Torah

Tags: torah-reading, sefer-torah, pentateuch-chumash

Is there a machine-readable Sefer Torah or Chumash? [Machine-readable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_data) meaning formatted as to be understood by a computer program. Despite the phrase, this is different from a Torah simply stored in some sort of electronic medium which though it can be read by a machine/program cannot be parsed meaningfully(understood). E.g. [Wikidata](http://www.wikidata.org/) is a machine-readable [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/)?

Comment: It takes a few minutes' research into Wikidata, which I'd never heard of before, to understand what you mean by "machine readable." This question would make more sense on its own if you'd include a clear explanation of what you mean by this term. "What are the implications ... ?" is too open-ended to be reasonably answerable. It should be removed or replaced with something much more specific, such as "If so, does that mean my calculator is required to keep the Seven Noahide Laws?" or whatever you had in mind.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Sefaria](http://sefaria.org)'s work, including [codifying](http://ludicanalytics.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/sefaria_in_gephi/) links between various texts machine-readably.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull what do you mean by 'implications'?

Comment: Not sure. The questions is broad, I imagine, because the implications are broad. Can a golem lain Torah?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org) has an API that will serve it up as a JSON object.

Comment: I think you have an answer to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52883/5323, also.

Answer (score 4):

[Mechon Mamre's "תיקון קוראים"](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cp/cp0.htm) (also [downloadable](http://mechon-mamre.org/dlcp.htm)) has each word of the Pentateuch in a separate `span` element; *pasuk*-final words have different attributes in those elements. This is thus a machine-parseable Pentateuch with machine-parseable delineation of *p'sukim*, which seems to be what you seek.

Comment: Thank you. Any comment on the implications for artificially intelligent readers?