# Recommendation for a digital Torah codex for software developers

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, pentateuch-chumash, english, text

Could someone recommend a source for a machine-readable Hebrew with English Torah codex that may be used in software development projects?

By "machine readable," I mean of a format that may be accessed programmatically and searched according to a criteria specified by the reader. Possible digital formats might include an ASCII text file, XML file or a commonly used database format.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya!  Could you [edit] your question to add a little more in the way of requirements?  What makes a source useful for software development?  Are there formatting requirements, for example?  Licensing ones?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for (*I'm still not sure I understand the definition of "machine readable"*), but you should take a look at the answers to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43921/5323).

Comment: Shokhet, Thank you most kindly for your response.  By machine readable, I mean of a format that may be accessed programmatically and searched according to a criteria specified by the reader.  Possible digital formats might include an ASCII text file, XML file or a commonly used database format.

Comment: Ah. So I was about to mark this question as a duplicate of the other, but this one adds English to the question, so it's a distinct question. Good luck on finding an answer!

Comment: Tip for you: if you want to be sure that someone (besides the post owner) will see your response to their comment, you should write their username, *preceded by the `@` symbol*. (*see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2067/5323*) I didn't see your response until I came back to the question.

Comment: Further tip: Clarifications should be [edit]ed into the question itself, rather than buried in comments where no one will see them. You can then comment (using `@`-notifications as suggested) to let the person who called for the clarification know that their suggestion has been acted on. (Incidentally, ASCII Hebrew is unlikely, though I suppose it could be possible if you're willing to accept transliterated Hebrew.)

Comment: @TRiG I would have edited that in myself, except for the fact that the words "machine readable" did not appear in this question, but rather in the *other* question, which I had linked to before. I was claiming lack of understanding of the *other* question; I thought this one was sufficiently clear.

Comment: @TRiG, could you clarify why ASCII Hebrew is unlikely? [It seems](http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp862.html) to be provided for by specification. Is the deal that native Hebrew content is likely to use a standard other than ASCII, not being American (the 'A')?

Comment: I don't know why that page calls itself "ASCII table for Hebrew". It's Code page 862. That is one of the many many encodings which are ASCII plus something else. These are sometimes called "extended ASCII", but that is not really a proper name for them. The only proper name is "Windows Code page 862".

Answer (score 5):

[Sefaria](http://sefaria.org) is a great resource for this sort of thing.

See their [developer documentation](http://www.sefaria.org/developers), and [terms of use](http://www.sefaria.org/terms) for more information.

They return results in JSON or JSONP.  Each translation has its own copyright issues which you'll have to deal with distinctly.

However, "codex" might be too strict of a term when talking about translations.

Comment: The Hebrew text underlying the Sefaria Miqra (great site!) is the (industry standard) [Westminster Leningrad Codex](http://www.tanach.us/Tanach.xml) - it is [CC licensed, unrestricted](http://www.tanach.us/License.html). Compare also the [Miqra according to the Mesorah](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/User:Dovi/Miqra_according_to_the_Mesorah) which is CC-BY-SA; see the Readme for details. I'm not sure about API's, etc., in either case, except that Westminster is available as XML. Perhaps worth noting, too, the [TanakhML Project](http://tanakhml.org/) which has some fascinating features.

Comment: @Davïd Sounds like you might be able to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

mechon-mamre.org

If you want Hebrew and English, they have http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm (using the JPS translation).

I don't know the details on the permissions issues.

Otherwise, try wikitext.

Comment: "You may use materials from this site only for your private study and teaching, not for publishing in any form, including any Web site.  Under our liberal understanding of the Fair Use Doctrine, you may use a few short quotations from our site in any other work, including copyrighted publications.  Any other use requires written permission from us." From http://www.mechon-mamre.org/

Comment: @Scimonster. Ah, thank you. The questioner wants something closer to public domain, I take it?